# How to pass file as an argument in a batch program

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I am new to batch file and I need to write a batch program that takes test1.txt as an argument
and out put test2.txt. 
I googled and checkd here, but couldn't find any sample code that takes file as an argument.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will iterate through the lines of the first command-line argument (`%1`) and the output file as the second argument (`%2`).

```
FOR /F %%l IN (%~1) DO (
    @ECHO %%l
) > "%%~2"
```

The example only copies the input (instead of filtering or transforming it). If you wanted to access pieces of the input line, you can assign it to a variable and use some of the substitution operators available to CMD (Look for "Environment variable substitution" in `for /?`).

This example filters out lines that begin with a hash (#).

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%l IN (%~1) DO (
    SET "LINE=%%~l"
    IF NOT "!LINE:~1:1!"=="#" ECHO %%l
) > "%%~2"
```